# C++ Access violation when passing variable

Tags: c++

Heres my problem, if I pass a variable from class A to class B via function, then in class B pass that variable to other functions for testing then it works fine. 
But if I pass the variable from A to B then try assigning it to a variable in class B, it gives the error for no reason

```
//Globals.h
enum TypeofObject { CIRCLE, SQUARE, RECTANGLE, DIAMOND };

//Object.h
#include "Globals.h"
class Object
{
    void Update();
private:
    TypeofObject currentObject;
    CollisionDetection * gameCollision;
};
//Object.cpp
void Object::Update()
{
    //Do stuff here
    gameCollision -> testCollision(currentObject);
}

//CollisionDetection.h
#include "Globals.h"
class CollisionDetection
{
public:
    void testCollision(TypeofObject currentObject);
private:
    void checkObjects(TypeofObject currentObject);
    TypeofObject currentObject;
}

//CollisionDetection.cpp
void CollisionDetection::testCollision(TypeofObject curObject)
{
    currentObject = curObject; //<- If I have this then it gives access violation error

    checkObjects(curObject); //<- Passing it from one function to the next works 
                             //fine but I want to assign it to currentObject so
                             //it doesnt need to be passed
}
```

Comment: I'd guess that `Object::gameCollision` is not initialised.

Comment: Your current object is private, you should use a pointer there. Let me try to be more 'clear': In your CollisionDetection class, try to make TypeofObject *currentObject, and receive a pointer to TypeofObject in  CollisionDetection::testCollision( Pointer here! ), then try to make currentObject = curObject;

Comment: @user2093113 we would get access violation at gameCollission->testCollision() if Object::gameCollission is not initialized.

Comment: @Jagannath: not necessarily. See http://ideone.com/bnk0oU

Comment: @AfonsoTsukamoto OP is taking of runtime error not compilation error.

Comment: @user2093113 That could be some dust-free environment. Anyways, checking for object validity is correct.

Comment: @Jagannath, didn't even thought about it. Access violations are not compile time errors? I'm kinda new to c++ but I always thought that access violations were caught in compile time due to the symbol table in the compiler.

Comment: The answers given are correct. Your curObject is not initialized correctly. I am commenting to mention that the system for collision detection that you are using is a little strange. Why do you want to handle collision with a 3rd party, non-manager class? Instead of objects asking if they collided, it is more efficient to have an entity manager that detects collision and then notifies the objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the issue here is that `Object::gameCollision` has not been initialised. The `CollisionDetection::testCollision` function is called correctly because you can imagine member functions as regular function taking an extra hidden parameter:

```
void CollisionDetection_testCollision(CollisionDetection *this,
                                      TypeOfObject curObject);
```

Given your definition, the function will run correctly up until the point where `this` is accessed:

```
currentObject = curObject; // this->currentObject = curObject
```

The line above is trying to set some memory at an offset from the `this` object. If `this` is not correctly initialised, the function will fail with an access violation.

I presume that `checkObjects(curObject)` does not fail because you are not accessing any of the data members of `CollisionDetection` in that function.